# Error deploying Fabric test-network fabcar chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following the documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html) to deploy a test network for Fabric on Ubuntu 16.04 on Amazon Lightsail.  All commands have been executed successfully with results as expected until

`./network.sh deployCC -l javascript`

The following error message is received:

`Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction 2554869d3683a7e77202f448aa201fd2f97243faa4ff5dd4839eb8d3175cf53b: could not launch chaincode fabcar_1:bec08b518fdb2bda0a0fb41a4a6f996a87ba08887583febedbc791cba7e91537: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Invoke execution on peer0.org1 peer0.org2 failed  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Any assistance will be tremendously appreciated.

K

Comment: can you please share the command to deploy the test-network,did you change the channel name or the chaincode name in the script?

Comment: The command used was: `./network.sh deployCC -l javascript`.  No changes to the script, channel or chaincode names made.

Comment: Can you shut down the network and make sure you removed the volume and certificates.And also remove the chaincode package which was created.

Comment: Executed `./network.sh down` before restarting from `./network.sh up`.  Same result.

Comment: which image version you are using of fabric and have you removed the volumes and certificates manually (not with the script).

Comment: I am on version 2.1.1.  After executing `./network.sh down`, there are no more containers listed using `docker ps -a`.  Where are these volumes and certificates located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is working as expected now. The issue had been with system sizing - increasing the memory to 4GB RAM fixed it

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.

K

Comment: Hi I have this error: rror: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': chaincode already successfully installed. Do you really solved it by system sizing?

Answer (score 1):

For fabcar sample, you can use `startFabric.sh` script inside fabcar to deploy chaincode with the language that you want. Specifically run `./startFabric.sh javascript` in your case.

This script generally runs `./network.sh` with some additional network cleanups.

Comment: I got this error: - `Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:9051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9051: connect: connection refused"`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are doing a fresh installation.First stop all the containers if it's not stop.

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

After that remove the unused volume using the command.

```
docker volume prune
```

or  `docker system prune` to remove any unused data.

You have to remove the certificates manually(if it's not deleted).First of all execute the `./network.sh down` command.Then go into the `test-network/organizations` and remove the content of `peerOrganizations` and `ordererOrganizations`

Then move to the fabric-ca directory and remove the content of `org1` ,`org2` and `ordererOrg,` keep in mind that in here you don't have to remove any `.yaml` file.
And remove the `fabcar.tar.gz` package in test network.

Now start the network using the commands below:

```
./network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.0.0

./network.sh deployCC -l javascript
```

Comment: Thank you for the steps.  They were all executed successfully prior to starting the network.  `./network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.0.0` was changed to `./network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.1.1` to match my version.  The execution was successful.  Upon executing `./network.sh deployCC -l javascript`, the following error was encountered `Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with javascript chaincode (it works 2 days ago, having the same error now), but deployCC with golang (weirdly) doesn't have this problem. So if using javascript is not a requirement you can also just run `./network.sh deployCC`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it terminated with the same error as the javascript chaincode: `Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed `.

Comment: have you tried resetting the fabric environment? Starting from the beginning of downloading fabric? That's what I did this morning

Comment: Yes, that didn't help much but let me try it again and I'll let you know if I get a different response today.

Comment: Unfortunately, still no joy.  I started from a fresh machine and that didn't help either.  If only there was a way to understand what the errors are.

Comment: you can change the docker compose configuration for container logging with either
`- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG` or
`- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=WARN:cauthdsl=info:policies=debug:msp=info` and edit as you see fit. then you can check peer container for the state before the error

Comment: Thanks.  Prior to the error, the following warning was intercepted - `could not launch chaincode 'fabcar_1:8140de38824ed03c21f9078a4f24d27a43912b6f26abdf01f5c92a28a800d264': chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0`.  I tried to Google it but wasn't able to find anything useful.  Do you have any insights?

Comment: check your stopped fabcar container `docker ps --filter "status=exited"` and see the logs inside of that said container

Comment: Executing that command yielded no results, i.e., no containers returned.

Comment: there's an ongoing discussions here as well https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric and they're fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Shut down your network. Then start it again. Then create a channel and deploy your chaincode. It will work.
I was getting same error because I created a named channel first and tried to deployed code there with -c. But when I shutdown and performed all steps again with default "mychannel" and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Could you format your answer a bit differently? Instead of saying "deployed with -c", replicate your command and use backticks to format the code `mycommand -c`. Also try using numbered steps to visually simplify your solution.