# Hyperledger Fabric, javascript fabcar chaincode error. Transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7051: connect: connection refused

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am having the same problem with **Hyperledger fabric 2.1.1**, but I am able to run test network with default options, but when I try to run **Fabcar javascript chaincode** I get an error:

`Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7051: connect: connection refused"`

I have tried everything mentioned in thread [Error deploying Fabric test-network fabcar chaincode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445415/error-deploying-fabric-test-network-fabcar-chaincode/62535955#62535955), removed docker images, ran prune, removed organizations data and fired `./network.sh up createChannel -ca -c mychannel -s couchdb -i 2.1.1`, but the error is still there. Also, my RAM is 16Gb, so the problem is not there. Any other suggestion, please ?

Comment: Can the container from wich you are trying to launch the chaincode have access to the port 7051 ?

Answer (score 1):

This situation is happened because you called a gRPC to 127.0.0.1:7051 server but your call failed to hit the server. This situation may happen for many reasons, but for most of the cases the situation is happened due to server down(server exit or down due to misconfiguration) or for wrong certificate or your call failed to hit the server due to misconfiguration.

Please check the following docker container and ensure that is running properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of docker images in your docker compose file to 2.2 and it will work.

For example:

From:
orderer.example.com:
container_name: orderer.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer

To:
orderer.example.com:
container_name: orderer.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.2