# Sample chaincode failing to create channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run the Token ERC-20 sample chaincode, using the hyperledger fabric binaries I built from source (I am trying to modify the source code, so it defeats the purpose to download pre-built binaries).

The first time I attempted this, everything worked fine. But for some reason, after rebuilding and updating the binaries, channel creation now fails.

Here's what's happening. I run this:

```
./network.sh up createChannel -ca
```

And I find the following warnings & errors in the output:

```
Local fabric-ca binaries and docker images are out of sync. This may cause problems.
```

and:

```
Error: Post "https://localhost:7053/participation/v1/channels": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7053: connect: connection refused

Channel creation failed
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390369/hyperledger-fabric-javascript-fabcar-chaincode-error-transport-error-while-di